# PRY Gem Issue When Loading Many Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, pry

I am having an issue with using the PRY console for Ruby.  When I fetch many records (e.g. Account.all) the output fills the page, and forces me to scroll to the end where I find an (END).  However I can't type anything and cannot return to the pry prompt.

If I type a similar command which doesn't return enough records to fill the terminal window, everything acts normally (i.e. Pry prints out the returned records and returns me to the prompt).

Any ideas?  I am using Pry version 0.9.10 on Ruby 1.9.3.

Thanks!

Comment: Try to type `q` so you can type other command

Comment: Ahh, thank you! That works, but why?  I didn't see any documentation on that?

Comment: please check my answer. I hope you can understand my explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `q` so you can type other command

---

#### Why?

The only thing that state pry have this feature is in here https://github.com/pry/pry#code-browsing

> Code that is longer than a page is sent through a pager (such as
> less),

If you are a Mac or Linux user you maybe are familiar with tools like Less or More that helps you see through documents by pagination in the terminal and pry implemented this feature as it's super useful sometimes when there is much things being printed out to the terminal.

To learn what you can do when in pagination mode in pry you should check this out http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/02/unix-less-command-10-tips-for-effective-navigation/